# How to calculate the value of the sum of squares defined as 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... +n2 until a user specified sum has been reached

Tags: python, while-loop

This is what I have, but I don't know what to make the range so that I can stop it when the sum is reached.

```
total=0
x=0
n=int(input('What is the maximum sum? '))
while x in range():
    x=x+1
    y= x**2
    total= total+y
    print(total)
    if total>=n:
        print('Done')
```

Comment: what should be the behaviour if the user specified sum isn't hit exactly?

Comment: It just needs to break at the last sum before going over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the bounds of the range in advance, one solution is to just use `while True:`, and use a `break` when you've reached the target:

```
while True:
    x = x + 1
    y = x ** 2
    total = total + y
    if total >= n:
        break
print(total)
```

---

If you want to get clever, though, you can think of this in terms of iterator pipelines. Like this:

```
numbers = itertools.count(1) # all positive integers
squares = (x**2 for x in numbers) # all squares of positive integers
totals = itertools.accumulate(squares) # all running totals of squares of ...
bigtotals = itertools.dropwhile(lambda total: total < n, totals) # all ... starting >= n
total = next(bigtotals) # first ... starting >= n
```

Comment: Well, the old code gave 1 for n=10, not 14, so I don't think I agree it's exactly the same.. but I'm glad it works now. :-)

Comment: @DSM: Isn't `accumulate` an iterator? Maybe it isn't… In which case, it's a perfect illustration of why it's not a good idea to write code that assumes that an iterable is an iterator. :)

Comment: I think it is, but since the `dropwhile` wasn't being bound to anything and `next` was acting on the `accumulate` result, it never had a chance to work its magic. That's my theory, anyhow..

Comment: @DSM: Oh, wait, after you call `next` on the `dropwhile` once, then the two are in sync, but if you never call it, yeah, nobody ever consumes anything. Never mind… (But still, a good illustration of "when possible, use what the docs guarantee, not what you can reason out should work but haven't bothered to test…".)

Answer (score 0):

This code will yield the highest total **equal to or below** the user specified sum:

```
total=0
x=0
n=int(input('What is the maximum sum? '))
while True:
    x=x+1
    y = x**2
    previousTotal = total
    total = total + y    
    if total == n:
        print total
        break
    if total > n:
        print previousTotal
        break
```

If you only need the first sum *greater* than the user specified total you can remove the last `if` statement and the `previousTotal` variable and change the first if statement to read `if total >= n:`.

If you need the *closest* sum to the user specified total (either higher or lower) you can calculate the absolute value of (n-previousTotal) and (n-total) and choose the lower.

The important thing is that `while True:` will evaluate literally "while True is True" which is effectively forever... therefore the `break` statements are needed to break out of the loop.

Note also that the above code works even if you remove:

```
if total == n:
    print total
    break
```

but will needlessly perform an extra evaluation of the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria should define the while loop. Is this what you're after?

```
total = 1
x = 1

n=int(input('What is the maximum sum? '))

while total <= n:
    print(total)
    x += 1
    total += x**2

print "Done -- stopped at ",(x-1),"^ 2"
```

Produces

```
> What is the maximum sum? 100
> 1
> 5
> 14
> 30
> 55
> 91
> Done -- stopped at  6 ^ 2
```